# Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.(…)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router

I got this error when I run this React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div id="root">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1></div>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

This is the error:

> bundle.js:1194 Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target
>   container is not a DOM element.(…)

Comment: did u define this id in ur html page ??

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/48938155eb24b4ccdde09426066869504c6dab3c/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  crossOrigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/ReactRouter.min.js"></script> -->

    <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>

  </body>
      <script src="/bundle.js"></script>

</html>
this is my index.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently you forgot to add the element  in your page that is the reason for which react does not find a container, to avoid this kind of problem you have to create a div element with identifier root or You have to change your selector.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div id="root">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1></div>,
  document.querySelector('body')
);
```

or

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to define this id `root` in your html page, your html page should contain this `id`, put this line inside body, it will work:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

You defined the `id` in a wrong place, use this part:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
     <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </div>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

In Html file:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

In JS file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general it should look like this -> `ReactDOM.render(Component, Container)`

document.querySelector() should point to the container in your index.html as Mayank suggested in the comments. (`document.querySelector('.container')`)

Please make sure to pass a react component you created like `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container')`

Comment: i have other issue 
i try this but it give me empty page without any error
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Request from 'react-http-request';
export default class App extends Component {
  render() { return (
      <Request
        url='https://api.github.com/users/mbasso'
        method='get'
        accept='application/json'
        verbose={true}>
        { ({error, result, loading}) => {
            if (loading) { return <div>loading...</div>;
            } else { return <div>{ JSON.stringify(result) }</div>;
            }}}
      </Request>  ); }}

Comment: Have you importet your App component into the js file with ReactDOM.render() ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `document.querySelector('root')` to `document.getElementById("#root")`.